# php imap_thread() for two mailboxes (inbox and sent)

Tags: php, email, imap

Official example in php.net for imap_thread works well for one mailbox. http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-thread.php However, in a real world, I need two mailboxes for threaded view (I want to see both messages I sent and received). Is it possible with this function? If not, how do I archieve that?

Comment: Ahem, what have you tried and how did it not work? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: I have tried the imap_thread() function. Since it works for one mailbox, but not for two, it didn't work out for me. PHP manual doesn't mention any similar functions, therefore I have no alternatives and I don't know what to do.

Comment: It's not possible. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: All mayor webmail client's like gmail offer threaded view. If it's not possible via imap_thread(), then how do they make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. You should get the headers of an email using [imap_fetchheader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchheader.php) method. You should look for the `Message-ID` header and the `In-Reply-To` header to see if emails are replied to each other (threads)